# How to get time zone offset for given timezone

Tags: julia

How get I get the current timezone offset from UTC for a given timezone?

```
Using Dates, TimeZones

t = tz”America/New_York”
get_offset(t)
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see on the [docs](https://timezonesjl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/types/), TimeZone.jl declare a VariableTimeZone  which doesn't have a defined offset from UTC because this offset can change over time (Spring/Winter time change). In this case, you can deduce the offset from a specific date:

```
julia> t = tz”America/New_York”
julia> typeof(t)
VariableTimeZone
julia> dt = DateTime(2014,10,26,2)
2014-10-26T02:00:00
julia> zdt =  ZonedDateTime(dt, t)
2014-10-26T02:00:00-04:00
julia> zdt.zone.offset
UTC-5/+1
```

However, "UTC+/-X" are declared FixedTimeZone and have already an offset.

```
julia> tz"UTC+1" |> typeof
FixedTimeZone
julia> t2 = tz"UTC-5"
UTC-05:00
julia> t2.offset
UTC-5/+0
```

Comment: To add to this answer, you can also look at `t2.offset.std` and `t2.offset.dst` to get some values of type `Second` that you can use for calculations.